# How to get a better branch coverage with Null value

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I am writing a test case for a method using `JUnit` and I am trying to cover a `null` condition for a better branch coverage. The problem is if I pass `null` as an argument the test case throws `NullPointerException` which is obvious but then how would I cover the branch coverage for the `Null` condition. `path` is a `String` parameter and I want to cover it in `if( path != null && path.length() > 0 )`. I haven't written a complete test case but I am confused how to write one for `null` condition.

Method under test

```
public String translateWebContextPathToVersionNo( String path ) {
    path = path.replaceAll( Constants.CONTEXT_PATH_ROS_PRODUCER_PROCESSOR, "" );
    path = path.replaceAll( Constants.CONTEXT_PATH_ROS_CONSUMER_PROCESSOR, "" );

    if( path != null && path.length() > 0 ) {
        String endChar = path.substring( path.length() - 1 );
        if( endChar.matches( pattern ) ) {
            path = path.substring(0, path.length() -1 );
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

JUnit test

```
@Test
public void testTranslateWebContextPathToVersionNo() throws Exception {
    TestQuartzROSServiceContextUtil util = new TestQuartzROSServiceContextUtil();
    util.translateWebContextPathToVersionNo(null);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you checking if it's null when you know it can't be? Either move the null check to the start of the method or ditch it.

Comment: @Mark and Tom. This is the reason I asked this question. I know it's behavior but still I have to write a `JUnit` for it and I am getting 50% branch coverage for the `path != null` and I wanted to know what if it is `null`.

Comment: As @MarkChorley said, `path` **cannot** be null at that line. If you want to catch a null input, it would have to be at the beginning of the method.

Comment: You are trying to do the impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 path = path.replaceAll( Constants.CONTEXT_PATH_ROS_PRODUCER_PROCESSOR, "" )
```

will throw a NullPointerException when path is null.

To avoid that, you should refactor the method and check for null before a method is called on a null object.

Comment: Thanks Kofislaper. I think I need to do something like this.